# phpmyadmin column using php function

Tags: php, mysql

Can i make a column that automatically creates its content from other column and do a function on it?

for example a function to lowercase the title in same row

```
function tt(row['title']){
    strtolower(row['title']);
}


[id     title     content     function tt()]
[1   Awesome PHP   Lorem       row['title']]

//becomes//

[id     title     content     function tt()]
[1   Awesome PHP   Lorem       awesome php ]
```

is that possible? Or do i have to make it is supposed to be while inserting the database?

Comment: yess you can with a [trigger](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html)

Comment: but not with a php function. You can use MySQL functions in a trigger.

Comment: so `LOWER()` then @spencer7593

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can use [triggers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html) to achieve this.